# Help sought with understanding an aspect of genitive/possessive

Tags: terminology, definiteness, armenian, genitive, nominalization

In English, we can use the possessive in such a way that the noun being described is omitted, chiefly in cases where it has already been introduced. For example; "This chair is mine, and that is John's" or "This is not only Sweden's problem, but also Finland's."

Coming into this without a linguistic background, I am unsure what the particular terminology is for the feature I described above. I have variously seen it described as 'genitive possessive', 'attribute nominalisation' and 'pseudo-double-definiteness'.

However, I notice that many languages do not have a separate form, in other words, as is the case in English, "John's" can mean either 'of John' or 'that of John'. I believe Finnish is another example where both forms would read simply as 'Johnin'.

However, in Armenian for example, there is a clear marked difference between the two forms.
Table = սեղան seghan
The table = սեղանը seghanə
of (the) table = սեղանի seghani
to the table (dative) - seghanin սեղանին
**that of the table = seghaninə սեղանինը**
the definite marker can also be amended to show possession, for example "that of my table" = սեղանինս seghanin(ə)s
"that of your table" = սեղանինդ seghanin(ə)d

The form can be further declined, for example "Ջոնի նկարները" Jonə nkarnerə" "John's things", but "Ջոնինից է" "Joninits e" "It's one of John's".

My questions are as follows:

What is the correct linguistic term for the feature described above?
Do you know any languages aside from Armenian which have a separate form/inflection for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I know nothing of Armenian, but you may be confusing two different morphological phenomena: genitive case and possessive affixes. Many languages have pronominal affixes on nouns that indicate who possesses them - in Turkish, for instance, _doktorum_ means 'my doctor', _doktoru_ means 'his/her doctor'. These are possessive affixes, or Px. But Turkish also has a genitive case, _-in_ that can be used in compounds. _Kadın_ means 'woman', and _kadının_ is its genitive. There are compounds _kadın doktor_ 'woman doctor', _kadın doktoru_ 'gynecologist', and _kadının doktoru_ '(the) woman's doctor'.

Comment: Forget 'possessive'. Genitive is the better term. In "This chair is mine, and that is John's". "John's is known as a fused determiner-head NP, understood as "John's chair". It's called 'fused' because the head and the determiner are combined, of fused, into the single word "John's"